# Match partial filetype in vimscript

Tags: vim, viml

I have a file that's being recognized as `jasmine.coffee` in VIM,
but `&filetype=='coffee'` evaluates to false.

Is there a way to do a partial filetype match in Vimscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `=~` pattern matching operator instead, which will treat the right side as a regular expression to test against.

```
&filetype =~ 'coffee'
```

This is mentioned in [the Conditionals section](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.4) of the Vimscript documentation.